# Sforce.console.isInConsole Not working

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console, inline-visualforce

I have an Inline VF page on a standard Account Page.

On click of a button inside VF, i am making a web service call and populating 2 fields inside VF.

In order to show the new values i am reloading the whole page in both Console and my system(normal) applications.

In order to identify which system i am using and to reload the proper record, i have written a JS. This JS is not working, please find the below code

```
<script src="/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

function checkConsole() {

alert('inside checkconsole function');

 if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) { 

    alert('check for cloud console');      
 //yes in console                                           
    window.top.location='/console';           

       } else {
   alert('check for system app');  

 window.top.location='/{!Account.id}';
    }
  }

</script>
```

When ever i execute from console , the application is not at all entering the IF condition (if (sforce.console.isInConsole())).

Has anyone implemented such requirement? Any help on this would be appreciated .

Thank you
Venkat

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to include the javascript integration library to make this work as expected.

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/30.0/integration.js"/>
```

Before Winter'16 it was enough to include the connection library, but it seems like Salesforce have updated this library and removed several methods.